# Erlang: Why Dialyzer does not notice this error?

Tags: erlang, typechecking, dialyzer

Now, I try to use Dialyzer and use *-spec*, *-type*.

I give the below code to Dialyzer, and I expected Dialyzer to notice "hoge(a) + 1 is invalid", but Dialyzer does not notice.

```erlang
-spec hoge (X) -> bad      when X :: a;
           (X) -> number() when X :: number().
hoge(X) when is_number(X) -> 1;
hoge(a) -> bad.

foo() ->
  _ = hoge(a) + 1.
```

But, in another setting,

```
-spec hoge (X) -> bad      when X :: a;
           (X) -> string() when X :: number().
hoge(X) when is_number(X) -> "1";
hoge(a) -> bad.


foo() ->
  _ = hoge(a) + 1.
```

Dialyzer tell me this error,

```
test.erl:12: The call erlang:'+'('bad' | [49,...],1) will never return since it differs in the 1st argument from the success typing arguments: (number(),number())
```

Why Dialyzer can't notice type-error in first setting.

```
-spec hoge (X) -> bad      when X :: a;
           (X) -> number() when X :: number().
```

This contract(specification) means not "hoge is typed of 'a' -> 'bad' | number() -> number()" but "'a' | number() -> 'bad' | number()"?

---

Here is a complete module for the first example.

```
-module(example).
-export([hoge/1, foo/0]).

-spec hoge (X) -> bad      when X :: a;
           (X) -> number() when X :: number().
hoge(X) when is_number(X) -> 1;
hoge(a) -> bad.

foo() ->
  _ = hoge(a) + 1.
```

Comment: I want to know how `-spec` information is used in type checking...

Comment: What version of OTP are you running? I tried with 18, 19 and 20, and in all cases Dialyzer reported the error in the first version of the code.

Comment: Really? I use Erlang/OTP 20, and Dialyzer version v3.2.4.

Comment: Can you post a complete module (but minimal) that shows the lack of a message.

Comment: I added a module to the post.

Comment: Ah, when the function hoge/1 is exported, you don't get the message. I think Dialyzer does not treat each call site separately. If hoge/1 is not exported, it knows that it will never return 1, because it's only called with a. If it is exported, it will be treated as returning either 1 or a, and one of those will make the addition work, so it's not deteted as an error.

Comment: Dialyzer succeeded in reporting the error! This specification of Dialyzer makes me confused... We have to pay much attention to -spec and -export...

Comment: Don't worry too much about things not being reported. Dialyzer will only report things that are absolutely, definitely wrong, and will keep quiet whenever there is still a possibility for the code to work in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard answer to "why Dialyzer doesn't catch this error" questions is always "because it is never wrong". Dialyzer never promises to find all errors.

---

In your problematic example, without the spec, Dialyzer's type inference algorithm indeed produces a union type for all the arguments and all the return values. With the spec, Dialyzer still infers the unions, but **should** have used the spec to narrow down the return value of the call and then produce an error. This looks like a case of "reduced sensitivity" (but not a bug, per se). You could, in any case, file a bug report.

In your working example, any possible value results in a bad result and Dialyzer's own type inference is enough, even without a spec.

Comment: The main difference was that in the first example, if the function hoge/1 is exported it will get a signature that could agree with the addition, while in the second example, it will never return anything that could make the addition work.

Comment: Right, this is due to the 'refinement' process that Dialyzer does if all the calls are known. But there should be an independent spec test that can detect that a call with `a` can never return a number.